# Square API: Extracting Client Details for Historic Transactions

Tags: transactions, square-connect

I am completely new to Square API, and I am not sure the data I'd like to extract is stored every time a transaction is processed.

I read the documentation and I can't find a clear reference on how long can one go into historical transactions for the clients that paid for them, or if their **data is automatically stored when payment is processed**, which is the key to my question.

I see it is possible to extract all historical transactions of a location. https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions

Do I understand correctly, it is possible to extract the customer details for each transaction? https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listcustomers

My end goal will be to discover customer details such as:

```
"id": "icard-card_id",
"card_brand": "VISA",
"last_4": "1111",
"cardholder_name": "Amelia Earhart",
"billing_address": {
  "address_line_1": "500 Electric Ave",
  "address_line_2": "Suite 600",
  "locality": "New York",
  "administrative_district_level_1": "NY",
  "postal_code": "10003",
  "country": "US"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have access to the customer information that is in the merchant's account. So if I am a merchant and I create a customer profile for one of my customers I can attach that customer to transactions that are created online and via Point of Sale, and then see the linked `customer_id` when I pull my transaction info. If no customer entity has been created by the merchant, or the customer is not linked to the transaction, you will not be able to see the info.

In general you never have any info that the merchant hasn't added to their customer directory (like email addresses linked to cards for receipts)